# What sources of free multispectral satellite imagery are there in Europe other than Sentinel 2?

Tags: remote-sensing

I am looking for free multispectral satellite imagery for north Germany prior to 2015. Does anyone have a list of sources?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @IanTurton Seeing that there is a finite list of free multispectral imagery available and the subject matter meets the site standards, this appears to be a good fit for GIS SE.

Comment: Thinking about this some more I would recommend you look on https://earthengine.google.com/ just to explore and play with some RS datasets that may be relevant. That is typically my first step to explore a dataset even though I typically pull it down to python for the real analysis.

Answer (score 2):

[Landsat](https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/) goes back to the 70s. You would want to look at Landsat 8, 7 and 5 for the time from the 2000s and 2010s.

You can download all Landsat imagery from [USGS' EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/.) website.